# Grails DSL configuration being ignored

Tags: grails, ehcache

Using Grails 2.2.3 and attempting to configure cache through the DSL as documented [here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-cache-ehcache/docs/manual/guide/usage.html) and [here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-cache/docs/manual/guide/usage.html).

The instructions point out that the configuration can be done either in the Config.groovy or CacheConfig.groovy file. 
This has to go under *grails.cache.config* key for Config.groovy or under key *config* for CacheConfig.groovy.

I am not trying to cache gorm operations. Hybernate is completely off. Need the approach to cache some REST results which turned out to be expensive and caching could be used...

I tried both options and this warning indicates the configurations are not being read:

```
WARN : net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory: No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/home/myhome/.grails/ivy-cache/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core/jars/ehcache-core-2.4.6.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
```

I am testing right now with this configuration in the CacheConfig.groovy

```
config = {
    cache {
        name 'someName'
        //Overwrite these, inherit rest
        timeToIdleSeconds 86400 //I like 24hours
        timeToLiveSeconds 86400
    }
    defaultCache {
        //Just inherit from defaults
    }
    defaults {
        timeToIdleSeconds 120
        timeToLiveSeconds 120
        eternal false
        overflowToDisk false
        maxElementsInMemory 10000
        maxElementsOnDisk 10000000
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
    }
}
```

Can this be a grails-cache-plugin bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That warning is for the Ehcache used in the Hibernate 2nd-level cache. It's saying that there's no ehcache.xml in the classpath (or explicitly configured elsewhere) so it's falling back to the default xml file in the jar file. This is separate from the Ehcache config used for the cache-ehcache plugin.

Comment: I am not using Hibernate at all. Any way to suppress the warning?

Comment: Sure, if you have an ehcache.xml file in src/java it will be copied to the classpath and used instead of the default in the jar. Extract ehcache-failsafe.xml from the jar, or use this (it's that file with the comments removed) the http://pastie.org/8882778